# Constant Base-url for Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, prestashop, constants, base-url

Hello i change a plugin create for Prestashop to Woocommerce, and i would Know if have a same constant _PS_BASE_URl__  ? I have see `WP_SITEURL` do it's work for woocomerce ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
site_url()
```

Regards